# Default dimensions sections name in book class

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, books, dimensions

Which are the default dimensions for the title of the sections chapter, section, subsection and so on for the book class?

Comment: What do you mean with dimensions? Font sizes? If you mean those that depends on the given parameter (base font size value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `book` uses by default `\huge` for `\chapter`, `\Large` for `\section`, `\large` for `\subsection`, `\normalsize` for `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`.

The sizes `\Large`, `\large` and `\normalsize` depend on the base font size of the document. For book they are defined in the files `bk12.clo`, `bk11.clo` and `bk10.clo`. So with option `12pt` `\Large` is 17.28pt and `\large` is 14.4pt, with option `11pt` `\Large` is 14.4pt and `\large` is 12pt, with option `10pt` (default) `\Large` is 14.4pt and `\large` is 12pt. `\normalsize` is always the basic size (from the option), but for `11pt` this is not 11pt but 10.95pt.

Answer (score 1):

The LaTex standard classes `article`, `report` and `book` are all documented in the file `classes.dtx`. Thus, your distribution most likely has a file `classes.pdf` or, if not, you can run LaTeX on the `.dtx`file to obtain it. This will give you all the glory details and more.

On my machine here (Mac OS) it is enough to say

```
texdoc classes
```

On windows there is a `texdoctk.exe` usually with a similar functionality

Comment: Nice. I'm on linux, how can I see that file?

Comment: @zar depends on your tex distribution, but most likely you have texdoc as well (OSX is more or less a unix so ...) and to search for the .dtx try  `kpsewhich classes.dtx`